# Update Stanfit object with new data

Tags: stan, rstan

I am generating data via API calls, one data point at a time. I want to feed each point to a Stan model, save the updated model, and discard the data point.

Is this possible with Stan?

If so, how do you deal with group-level parameters? For example, if my model has J group-level parameters, but I'm only inputing one data point at a time, will this not generate an error?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be conceptualized as Bayesian updating. In other words, you beliefs about the parameters are currently represented by some joint distribution, then you get one more data point, and you want to update your beliefs in light of this data point. And then repeat that process.

If so, then you can do a Stan model that has only one data point, but you need some way of representing your current beliefs with a probability distribution to use as the prior. This typically would be done with some multivariate normal distribution on the parameters in the unconstrained space. You can use the `unconstrain_pars` function in the rstan package to obtain a matrix of unconstrained posterior draws and then see what multivariate normal it is close to. You probably want to use some shrunken covariance estimator for the multivariate normal if you have a lot of parameters. Then, in your Stan program use a multivariate normal prior on the parameters and do whatever transformations you need to do to get transformed parameters in the constrained space (many such transformations are documented in the Stan User Manual).

It is true that when you estimate a hierarchical model with only one data point, that data point has essentially no information about the groups that the particular data point are not in. However, in that case, the margins of the posterior distribution for the parameters of the omitted groups will be essentially the same as the prior distribution. That is fine.